# Передача параметра между событиями

Tags: c#, события, global-variables

Есть

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

И есть

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Как мне передать между этими событиями переменную x?
В теории кнопка должна установить значение переменной x
    x=150
и запустить таймер

```
timer1.Enabled = true;
```

и таймер должен принять этот x и обработать его по своей логике.
Пробовал создавать промежуточную переменную

```
public x {get;set}
```

и присваивать на нее значение, потом забирать в таймере, но это не работает.

Comment: Вам необходимо именно "создавать промежуточную переменную public x {get;set} и присваивать на нее значение, потом забирать в таймере". Поэтому добавьте в вопрос код, который не работает. Обычно проще найти ошибку в нем, чем угадать код, который у вас заработает.

Comment: private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer2.Enabled = true;
            y = 175;
        }                                                                                                                                                       public int y { get; set; }
        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int now_y = this.pictureBox1.Location.Y;
            if (y>now_y)
        }

Comment: Вообще, судя по вашему коду, у вас не назначен тип поля **x**, попробуйте указать тип, и снова скомпилировать.

Comment: @Birdy в действительности обозначен тип int, выше я написал код но не знаю как его форматировать в комментариях

Comment: в любом Windows form элементы есть свойства 'Tag' можно воспользоваться с этим пустым свойством .Это создана для передачи дополнительной информации. допустим у вас есть timer : timer1.tag = 150; private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Timer timer = (Timer)sender;
            int value = Convert.ToInt32(timer.Tag);
        } когда таймер будет работать